# Cat files into a new files in multiple sub directories

Tags: cat, subdirectory

I would like to be able to find the sub directories in a folder
Then located the .txt files in each sub folder
Then CAT those files in each sub folder into a new .txt file within that folder.

This is what I am using now but it does not work:

find . -type d -exec find .{} -type f -iname *.txt* \; -exec cat {} >> all.txt \;

any help would be most appreciated.

Thanks
B

Comment: note the low number of "watchers" for  your 2 tags. Better to indicate unix/linux, bash/ksh/csh(?)/etc. What's wrong with just searching from `.` dir for `-type f -name '*.txt'`?. Keep it simple;-). Read about `\+` instead of `\;` for effiencies sake (or `xargs`). Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a Bash for-Loop, this should work:

```
for sub_dir in $(find ./ -type d -not -name '.'); do
    cat $sub_dir/*.txt > $sub_dir/all.txt;
done
```

Use all the subdirs found by find (excluding the . directory) and issue a cat on each one of them.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but it does not seem to be working. I get the concept and it seems like it should work but alas, my all.txt files are all empty still. I'll keep plugging away.

Comment: What shell are you using? I tried it in bash and got the desired results (besides some errors with sub-directories without *.txt files.

Comment: I was using the wrong shell. Once switched to bash it did indeed work fine. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

find . -name "*.txt" -type f -exec cat {} + > all.txt

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).